# How to do paging or ordering by taking the reference var Using DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt, datatables

I am Using Datatables  [datatables.net](https://www.datatables.net/) for doing grouping,paging or sorting.I want to take reference variable of datatables initialisation and apply gouping or paging based on sutiation.See the code Below.

```
var table=$('#table_Id0').dataTable();
```

Here all the functionality is working but i don't all the functionality at a time.It should be dynamic based on condition.Is there any way can we take this reference variable "table" and apply some logic like paging false.

```
table.paging:false
```

How to apply logic on reference variable.Any suggestion?

Comment: In general you cannot.  The reason is, that many options involves a lot of bahind-the-scenes calculation, caching and DOM-building. What you must do is to reinitialize the table with the new options.

Comment: Thanks david..what is the other way to do this..since i need dynamic way..i  am using this datatables in GWT application using JSNI Method.

Answer (score 1):

Just reinitialize the table by either passing the `destroy` option or by destroying the instance manually with `destroy()` before you do. Here an example with a select box where the user can choose paging :

```
<select id="paging">
    <option value="true">paging on</option>
    <option value="false">paging off</option>
</select>
```

declare an `options` object holding all your initial options :

```
var options = {
    destroy : true,
    paging : true
    //other options goes here
};
```

when the user choose a new option in the paging select :

```
$("#paging").on('change', function() {
    options.paging = $('#paging').val()=="true" ? true : false;
    table = $("#example").DataTable(options);
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/o3sgfv9g/**

This demonstrates the way to reinitialize the table with new or altered options, now you just do the same according whatever "situation" or "condition" you are referring to in the question.

**Note**: Have used 1.10.x notation since you are referring to `paging`, not 1.9.x `bPaginate`.